# What causes the "Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Append" error?

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm very new to mathematica (I just started using it today), I was wondering if someone could explain to me what is wrong with the following piece of code:

`NIntegrate[A*(eta^3)*(Exp[-3 N]/H)*gamma, {N, 0, 60}]`

`eta = 3.21+Erfi[Sqrt[N + 1/2]] - Erfi[Sqrt[1/2]]`
`H = Sqrt[1 + (2*N)]`
and gamma = e^K for some unknown variable K

A, eta, H, and gamma (eta, gamma and H are all functions of N) have all been defined previously.
eta contains the Erfi function, and mathematica doesn't seem to beable to solve this analytically, so i used the NIntegrate function instead.

However i get the following errors:

1: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Append[NIntegrate`StrategiesDump`prepOption,Method->GlobalAdaptive].

2: Append called with 3 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected.

3: NIntegrate: Append[NIntegrate`SymbolicPreprocessing,NIntegrate`StrategiesDump`prepOption,Method->GlobalAdaptive] is not a valid specification of an integration strategy or rule.

I was wondering if someone could explain to me why this doesn't work?

thanks.

Comment: "A, eta, H, and gamma (eta, gamma and H are all functions of N) have all been defined previously." Without the definitions we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: eta = 3.21 + Erfi[Sqrt[N + 1/2]] - Erfi[Sqrt[1/2]], H = Sqrt[1 + (2*N)], and i made a mistake as gamma is not a function of N, it's a function of some unknown varaible K。

Comment: Edit your question to include **all** of the required definitions.

Comment: [4. Avoid single-letter capltal names for your variables.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999)

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

User-defined names should not start with capital letters to avoid potential conflicts with built-in names. For example,

```
?N
```

[image]

```
eta[n_] = 321/100 + Erfi[Sqrt[n + 1/2]] - Erfi[Sqrt[1/2]];
h[n_] = Sqrt[2 n + 1];
```

A numeric technique such as [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) cannot evaluate with any undefined values (e.g, `a`, `gamma`). You must assign numeric values prior to calling `NIntegrate`

```
int[a_?NumericQ, gamma_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[a*(eta[n]^3)*(Exp[-3 n]/h[n])*gamma, {n, 0, 60}]
```

For a bounded range the min and max values are

```
#[{int[a, gamma], -2 <= a <= 2, -2 <= gamma <= 2}, {a, gamma}] & /@ 
   {NMinimize, NMaximize}

(* {{-56.1441, {a -> -2., gamma -> 2.}}, {56.1441, {a -> 2., gamma -> 2.}}} *)
```

Plotting over a range of values

```
Plot3D[int[a, gamma], {a, -2, 2}, {gamma, -2, 2},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"a", "gamma", "int"})]
```

[image]